# any rational function on $\Bbb P^1$ is constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What is the flaw in the answer for proving any rational function on $\Bbb P^1$ is constant?

Let $\phi: \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb A^1$ be a rational function. Since $\Bbb A^1 \subset \Bbb P^1$ we can think $\phi: \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^1$ as rational function. As every rational map from $\Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^n$ is regular, so $\phi$ is regular. We also know that any regular function on $\Bbb P^1$ is constant, so $\phi$ is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular *function* on a variety $X$ is, by definition, a regular map $X\to \mathbb{A}^1$.  Just because every regular function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is constant, that doesn't mean that every regular *map* to a variety other than $\mathbb{A}^1$ is constant.  In particular, $\phi$, being a regular map $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$, need not be constant.